# Add Crystal Reports into Eclipse to work with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, crystal-reports

I am trying to add Crystal Reports plugin to Eclipse in order to create reports in Java. I downloaded [the manual installation package](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-29757) and installed it manually. (Extracted the downloaded zip file to the eclipse dropins folder)

But I see I have no way of creating a crystal report project in Eclipse. What I can see is only this.

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Comment: Don't use code formatting if it isn't code.

Comment: I fixed the wording for the link in your question so the text matches what the link goes to. It's usually recommended to avoid links where the text is just a single word like "here" or "this", as it doesn't give an indicator as to what the link is for.